# How to schedule builds in VSTS on specific time?

Tags: azure-pipelines

I need to schedule build in `VSTS` on specific time and days of week.

I did quick search in the Internet and didn't find any guides for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You need to go on `Edit` page of your build definition.
2. Then on tab `Triggers`.
3. Optional: If you want to build **only on specific times** (not with each commit): Under `Continuous integration`, uncheck checkbox `Enable continuous integration`
4. Click on `Add` button for `Scheduled` option.
5. Choose days of week and time to run build.
6. Pay attention to option `Only schedule builds if the source or pipeline has changed`.
7. Select required branch.

Check screenshots below:
[image: Initial Triggers page]

[image: Settings of Triggers page]

Comment: @Shayki Abramczyk, you are right! I've updated the answer.

Comment: Great! I deleted my comment.